# Android Annotation

Tags: android, android-annotations

It's now been around 5-6 month since I am  working on android. Gone through few points and still in the process of learning. Few days back I came to know about **android annotations**. Great way to reduce our code and strictly concentrate on BL. But for continue learning about annotation I need stuff which I am not getting in much details. I found few of the good stuff, **like [simple annotation example](http://androidannotations.org/)** and also **github** provided me few more **example as [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Cookbook)**. But still I really want to dig a more deeper as far as annotation is concern. 
*Where can i find more stuff related to Annotation?* Can anybody help me in this. I know this is not directly related to programming, but ya *still require help of programmers only*.

***Updated***: I just got one more link for annotation, pasting to update users. [Here the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820463/is-androidannotaions-reliable)

Comment: I guess still need to work in details and still need to do R&D on annotation. I don't know whether to accept below answer or still wait for some genuine answer although i know there is no exact answer for my question. So still waiting for something more useful.
`PS: I never said dayS answer was not useful`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for exactly.
AndroidAnnotation will generates a class A_ with an annotated class A. You can open A_ and see what is generated.

If you wan't to know a little more about annotation in itself, you can check this article http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html
Quickly, annotation processing works this way :

- Analyze a class to extract a list of methods and attributes
- For each method and attribute, if there are annotations on them, make some stuffs (generating code, ...)

I hope I gave you some answers.

EDIT: If you wan't some feedbacks, me and my co-workers are using AndroidAnnotations for a big company for one year now and it works perfectly. We can really focus on functionalities.

Comment: Hey thanks dayS for answering, but still, as per introduction is concern I have attached above links that gave me introduction for the android-annotations. And with some syntax of each. But here I need few working demos which we easily get for android or java. Any pdf's or book name explaining me android-annotations will also help. thanks any ways.

Answer (score -1):

[LightAndroidAnnotation](https://github.com/kim-wang-bj/LightAndroidAnnotation) is a very small Android annotation library. All the annotation implementation codes are just in one class: [Injector.java](https://github.com/kim-wang-bj/LightAndroidAnnotation/blob/93f9265d98552dc68b17526c53e8c1e01ba9b400/light-android-annotation/src/main/java/com/wq/android/lightannotation/Injector.java)

It is only some basic usage of Java reflection and annotation. May help you.